# How can I display iPad content fullscreen with HDMI on a TV?

Tags: ipad, hdmi, fullscreen, television

I bought an iPad lately (10.5" 2017), and I want to connect it via HDMI to my HDTV. Now I know that because of the iPad screen size, I cannot get fullscreen on my TV (I have black borders right and left right now).

But, is there **any** way I can make it work?

I use this iPad for travelling and would love to plug it into a hotel TV and watch Netflix on it. But I would like to display the content fullscreen without the black borders!

Comment: Have you tried the Netflix app?  When I connect my iPad via HDMI using the app, the aspect ratio of the media is preserved.  Particularly for movies that are 16:9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are apps that detect if your iPad is mirrored to an external device via HDMI and adjust to fit accordingly.  For example, the official **Netflix** app outputs the original aspect ratio to the external screen.  The device displays the message "Now playing on your TV" as noted in the attached screen shot.  The TV displays the show at the proper aspect ratio depending on its settings.

Keynote and other apps work similarly.  It would depend largely on the aspect ratio of the TV show or Movie being played.

[image: Streaming to TV via HDMI]

Comment: Unfortunately "Now playing on TV" only works while streaming. I wanted to use the download function when up in my cabin, but then it only plays in mirrored mode, which means 16:9 is playing inside 4:3 (wide black borders).

Comment: That is a matter for the developers. I suggest sending feedback to Netflix. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

After some discussion with the Netflix chat support I got this confirmed. It has now been reported to the development team and hopefully they will improve the iOS app in the future so that downloads too will use the "now playing on TV" feature for full frame width on a TV with iPAD (4:3) as the source.

Answer (score 0):

As someone has stated, it's really a developer issue. The best solution I've found is using the zoom function on the television, if it has one. My girlfriend's television has a zoom setting called Cinema or Cinematic, which aaaaalmost gets the image to a 16:9 aspect ratio once again with non-streaming content.

Answer (score -1):

You can adjust the screen size on your tv. It worked for me.